# Use dynamic AJAX URL for Vue Select2 wrapper component

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs2, jquery-select2

I modified the [Wrapper Component Example](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/examples/select2.html)
from the VueJS documentation to include the AJAX datasource option. [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/saadbinmahbub/6g51mgvj/) is my code.

However, I would like to set the `ajax` `url` **property of my select2 component dynamically** preferably like this,

```
<select2 :options="options" v-model="selected" url="dynamic-url-here">
  <option disabled value="0">Select one</option>
</select2>
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Add the property to the Component's `props`:

   ```
   Vue.component('select2', {
       props: ['options', 'value', 'url'],
   ```
2. Move the AJAX options either to a variable with scope outside the select2 component or a data element of that component:

   ```
   Vue.component('select2', {
       props: ['options', 'value', 'url'],
       template: '#select2-template',
       data: function() {
         return {
             ajaxOptions: {
                 url: this.url,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 delay: 250,
                 tags: true,
                 data: function(params) {
                     return {
                         term: params.term, // search term
                         page: params.page
                     };
                 },
                 processResults: function(data, params) {
                     params.page = params.page || 1;
                     return {
                         results: data,
                         pagination: {
                             more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
                         }
                     };
                 },
                 cache: true
             }
         };
     },
   ```
3. use that variable when initializing the select2:

   ```
   mounted: function() {
       var vm = this
       $(this.$el)
          .select2({
              placeholder: "Click to see options",
              ajax: this.ajaxOptions
          })
   ```
4. Add a watcher for *url*:

   ```
   watch: {
       url: function(value) {
           this.ajaxOptions.url = this.url;
           $(this.$el).select2({ ajax: this.ajaxOptions});
      }
   ```
5. Set the property:

   ```
   <select2 :options="options" v-model="selected" :url="url">
   ```

   where `url` is defined in the *data* object of the app.

See a demonstration in [this plunker example](http://plnkr.co/edit/6i8IoJAecmu1DbBLcPFx?p=preview).

Comment: I found a temporary work around by adding `data-url` property to `<select2>` tag and fetching it in my component using `vm.$el.dataset.url,`. This is great, Thank you.

Comment: It works but how to call ajax only after 3 char entered @SAMOnela