# How to pass dynamic ajax-url for vue-select while function called for search event?

Tags: ajax, vue.js, v-select

I want to make use one function for multiple  component in vue-js. To do so i need to make two things dynamic - 1.ajax-url and 2. dataset holder for options. I read https://sagalbot.github.io/vue-select/docs/Advanced/Ajax.html as per this function working fine. i have following code-

```
<v-select :options="fieldSet[name].dataSet" :url="/user/autocomplete?term=" @search="onSearch">
    <template slot="no-options">
            <button class="btn btn-block">Add New Item</button>
    </template>
</v-select>
```

onsearch method is as follows as given in above link -

```
// here search and load parameter gives searchText and spinner for UX
onSearch: function onSearch(search, loading) {
    loading(true);
    // this.search(loading, search, this);
    // here i want to get options holder and ajax-url so that i can 
    // fetch data using ajax and assign to some dynamic variable (which is defined for particular field)
},
```

> What i looked into is - 
>   [Use dynamic AJAX URL for Vue Select2 wrapper component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46425172/use-dynamic-ajax-url-for-vue-select2-wrapper-component)
>   , but could not determine what to do for v-select.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some time before I faced same problem, i made following changes on `/node_modules/vue-select/dist/vue-select.js` and changes are equals to changes in two files -- `/node_modules/vue-select/src/mixins/ajax.js` and `/node_modules/vue-select/src/components/select.vue`,

> It has two steps first change $emit.function parameters and register your new variable as props

make search for `onSearch:{type:Function,default:function(t,e){}}}` and i made it like `onSearch:{type:Function,default:function(t,e,url){}}}` because this make search function will return three parameters..

and search for `watch:{search:function(){this.search.length>0&&(this.onSearch(this.search,this.toggleLoading),` and change it to `watch:{search:function(){this.search.length>0&&(this.onSearch(this.search,this.toggleLoading,this.ajaxUrl,this.optionHolder),` because this will return 4 parameters ajaxUrl and optionHodler and watch them ,

now we need to return them using `$emit`

make a search for `this.$emit("search",this.search,this.toggleLoading))}` and change it to `this.$emit("search",this.search,this.toggleLoading,this.ajaxUrl,this.optionHolder))}` this will return four variables making them accessible globally ...

Now register your new parameter in select.vue file by changing following -
make search for`props:{value:{default:null},` and place these two these `ajaxUrl:{type:String,default:''},optionHolder:{type:String,default:''},` defination after search text ...

this is working for me ... let me know whether it worked for you or not?